# C# DynamicMethod Could not load type

Tags: c#

I am trying to use DynamicMethod with a Type from another assembly. The assembly is loaded and I can use the Type perfectly fine. But when I try to use it in a DynamicMethod it throws an exception.

Could not load type 'TheClass' from assembly 'SomeModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Comment: Is the assembly referenced by your calling assembly? Or have you loaded it via LoadAssembly?

Comment: Is TestClass an owner of DynamicMethod or you use TheClass type within the body of the method?

Comment: It is being used inside the DynamicMethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Type was being compiled as internal instead of private.